# Change origin of WKWebView in iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I have an iOS hybrid app centred around a `WKWebView` loading local web assets with [`loadFileURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:). The `WKWebView` communicates over HTTPS to a backend API with `jQuery.ajax`. The app is mobile-only and I want the API to also be "mobile-only". That is, I want to block browsers such as Chrome and Firefox from using the API.

My strategy is to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on API responses as follows:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: app://myApp
```

Can I change the origin of the `WKWebView` to `app://myApp` to avoid browsers from querying the API?

Answer (score 5):

**Case:1**

You can inject a JS into WKWebview at time of document creation or document finished loading and hook the java script XMLHTTPRequest open method with your custom implementation to add this custom header for all the AJAX requests from WKWebView.

example code

```objectivec
NSString *XMLHTTPRequestHookJSPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"XMLHTTPRequestHook.js" ofType:nil];
NSString *kXMLHTTPRequestHookJS = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:XMLHTTPRequestHookJSPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
WKUserContentController *contentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:kXMLHTTPRequestHookJS injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:NO];
[contentController addUserScript:script];
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.userContentController = contentController;

self.lastUsedWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.webContainerView.bounds configuration:configuration];
self.lastUsedWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
```

And in the XMLHTTPRequestHook.js try to hook XMLHttpRequest with your custom implementation to add this custom header and call back the original open method.

**Case 2**
If you want this header to be added while loading the URLRequest in WKWebview , you can add this header to NSMutableRequest as below and load this request in WKWebview. However with this method you may not have this header in all the AJAX calls from WKWebview.

example code:

```objectivec
WKWebView * webView = /*set up your webView*/
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/index.html"]];
[request addValue:@"app://myApp" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"];

// use stringWithFormat: in the above line to inject your values programmatically
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Chandra. On the app side I am looking to change the `origin`. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is added by the API server responses!

Comment: Hi ..If you are looking for something like NSURLProtocol to intercept the network request from WKWebview , NSURLProtocol doesn't work with WKWebview as WKWebview load all the network requests from a different process. However you case still try solution mentioned above in case1 to change the headers to required values for all the AJAX calls from WKWebview and see if that help.

Comment: Also, You can alter your strategy and add a custom header(instead of using Access-Control-Allow-Origin header) for all the AJAX calls from WKWebView and in your API server you can use this custom header to identify that the api calls are from your app and not from any other browser.Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Browsers can add customer headers with JavaScript. From a security perspective this doesn't help unless you are happy with the latency of the CORS OPTIONS preflight, which I'm now.